# "push back" vs "push back on"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I saw one expression from my email: "What asks are we willing to push back on?"

Usually, "push back" is what I use. but here, what meaning does this "on" add?

Comment: I have an off-topic question: what does "what asks" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"what asks" is not correct English, or at least I have never so regarded it. I suspect it means "what requests" If so, the statement as a whole means "What requests will we insist on responses to?" or perhaps "What requests will we try to get action on."

(I see from the comments that at least one dictionary considers this an acceptable use of "ask", although informal and  "chiefly British". So it seems that "not correct" is too strong, but I would advise against musing it in US English. In any case "requests" conveys the meaning.)

If someone objects to a particular decision, they are said to "push back on" that item. "Push back" without the "on" would have a significantly different meaning. As a verbal phrase, it would mean "return" or perhaps "reject" so "What requests would we push back?" would mean "which ones would we return to the originator" or perhaps "which ones would we reject without consideration".

As a phrasal noun "push back" usually means "objections". For example:

> The council announced a tax increase but got lots of push back.

I usually see "push back" in political or public relations contexts, often in new reporting. It is a somewhat informal term.

Comment: [Ask](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ask) as a noun meaning "something that is asked for" is in the dictionary, though it is marked as *informal*. I think of it as "business speak."

Comment: @Canadian Yankee Well if i heard that used in a business context, i would think that the person saying it was not a native speaker, at least not of US English. I don't recall ever hearing it in such a context. I see the dictionary entry also says "chiefly British".

Comment: @Canadian Yanke I have modified the answer in light of your comment and the dictionary entry.

Comment: You both are geniuses. The person who wrote this is a Canadian. :) Thank you for very clear explanation!!!

Comment: You can see "ask" used as a noun in [this Washington Post headline](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/01/15/daily-202-biden-throws-obama-era-caution-wind-with-big-ask-coronavirus-stimulus/): "Biden throws Obama-era caution to the wind with a big ask for coronavirus stimulus"